# Integrate APISIX with Keycloak: Overlapping routes introduce issue in Discovery

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, config, openid-connect, apache-apisix

I am using keycloak as an oidc provider. I have added two routes in apisix config.

1. uri : "/auth" related apis to keycloak
2. uri:"/*", other than keycloak APIs to my mock app(traefik whoami)
   While accessing my application(foo.example.com),I am getting 500 in discovery.

My route configs:

```
### Keycloak service
curl -XPUT localhost:xxxx/apisix/admin/routes/1 -H "X-API-KEY: xxxx" -d '{
    "uri":"/*",
    "service_id": "2",
    "hosts": ["foo.example.com"],
    "methods": ["GET","POST","PUT","DELETE"],
    "priority": 10,
    "plugins":{
        "openid-connect":{
            "client_id": "foo",
            "client_secret": "ATfWp96az8uTStNSr7qYKSrlXpFqm35b",
            "discovery": "http://foo.example.com/auth/realms/foo/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            "scope": "openid profile",
            "bearer_only": false,
            "realm": "foo",
            "introspection_endpoint_auth_method": "client_secret_post",
            "redirect_uri": "http://foo.example.com/",
            "logout_path": "/logout",
            "set_refresh_token_header":true,
            "post_logout_redirect_uri":"http://foo.example.com/"
        }
    }
}'

### Whoami service
curl -XPUT localhost:xxxx/apisix/admin/routes/2 -H "X-API-KEY: xxx" -d '{
    "uris": ["/auth/*", "/auth/"],
    "service_id": "1",
    "hosts": ["*.example.com"],
    "methods": ["GET","POST","PUT","DELETE"],
    "priority": 999
}'
```

While accessing foo.example.com, I am expecting keycloak login page.
But i am getting 500, I can see some error in apisix logs.

Here is my error:

> [lua] openidc.lua:573: openidc_discover(): accessing discovery url
> (http://foo.example.com/auth/realms/foo/.well-known/openid-configuration)
> failed: timeout, client: 172.19.0.7, server: _, request:
> "GET /auth/realms/foo/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1",
> host: "foo.example.com"

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems APISIX is not able to resolve the domain foo.example.com and connect to Keycloak. Double check the DNS configurations to ensure APISIX is able to configure the Keycloak hostname